# Enable WCF message logging programmatically (from loaded .dll)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've read the disappointing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600053/how-to-enable-wcf-message-logging-from-code-instead-of-the-application-configurat) regarding enabling logging of WCF messages from code, but thought that maybe since then there may be other suggestions for how to do this. I'm working under the constraints of developing a .NET 3.5 library that gets loaded (via COM) into a larger win32 framework. As such, I do not have control of the contents of any app.config file.

Is there any way (Reflection to access internal classes? Some other nastiness?) to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have any problem with configuration based logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to solve this by adding an IClientMessageInterceptor, used [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S5) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service should have an interface, correct? Use an IOC container (windsor, for example) to instantiate the WCF service, and add logging around it using interceptors: 
http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/05/adding-behavior-without-modifying-existing-code-with-windsor/
I'm not sure if this is the level of logging you are asking for, but that's one option.

The other option is to implement Log4Net (or another logging provider) and configure the logger in code:
[log4net pure code configuration with filter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885378/log4net-pure-code-configuration-with-filter-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already using Ninject for the project so using an Interceptor would work well. I just managed to solve this in a "good enough" way by implementing my own IClientMessageInterceptor based on this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S5